# HTML href to Youtube and Twitter "refuse to connect"

Tags: html, href

I'm trying to do a simple href to my Twitter and Youtube channel but both come up with "twitter.com refused to connect" or "youtube.com refused to connect." I'm not sure what the issue is and I've tried with other sites but keep getting "{site} refused to connect." I've also tried with a simple href with no classes and the same results. Here is the code.

```html
<ul class="social-buttons">
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/TylerFlar" class="btn btn-just-icon btn-simple btn-twitter">
                            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcvcqbRiPopzRCTSmm_Oi4g" class="btn btn-just-icon btn-simple btn-youtube">
                            <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

I'm using Xammp Apache to run my site, maybe that has a problem with hrefs?

Comment: It work for me from an HTML page with script or styling. Try `curl -I https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcvcqbRiPopzRCTSmm_Oi4g`  from the server and see if it's blocked.

Comment: For me it worked by adding a `target="_[whatever]"` to each anchor tag. Just specify the `target` you prefer for your page.

Comment: @JeffBerlin adding the target anchor tag worked, thank you!

Comment: And @medic17 thanks for showing me that command because it seems useful if I run into other problems.

Comment: @JeffBerlin Please move your comment to an answer so OP can accept, the community sees the answer easier, and you can gain rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `target="_[whatever]"` attribute to the anchor elements:

```
<ul class="social-buttons">
  <li>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/TylerFlar" class="btn btn-just-icon btn-simple btn-twitter" target="_blank">
      Twitter
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcvcqbRiPopzRCTSmm_Oi4g" class="btn btn-just-icon btn-simple btn-youtube" target="_blank">
      Youtube
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Working CodePen](https://codepen.io/jeffberlin/pen/VwvNwpb)